# ASP.net MVC dynamically alter database structure and update model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am in phase of designing architecture of my web application. I want to work with asp.net mvc5 and oracle database at back end.

One basic requirement of my project is that the application's admin users can add/remove Form Fields. I want to physically add/remove columns in my database tables at run time (not design time).

How can I achieve it in mvc and how the models can be updated dynamically at run time?

Should I use some ORM or how I design data access layer for that?

I just need suggestions and hints for the architecture design approaches.

Comment: Take a look at EAV model for relation DB like ORACLE or try to use NoSQL database that whats its made for;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of physically adding and removing the fields at runtime you can try the following table structure

```
Field Name              Field Type
CustomField1Name        Nvarchar(256)
CustomField1Value       Nvarchar(Max)
CustomField1IsVisible   Bool
CustomField1FieldType   Nvarchar(32)  [char/numeric/bool etc]
CustomField1Required    Bool

CustomField2Name        Nvarchar(256)
CustomField2Value       Nvarchar(Max)
CustomField2IsVisible   Bool
CustomField2FieldType   Nvarchar(32)
CustomField2Required    Bool
```

If you need any more field specific information like custom validation you can add here.

Repeat this for how many custom fields you want . Due to this design, in run time  there will be no structure changes in DB level. All changes you can do in coding level.

Comment: EAV is a good approach but in my case, the requirement of add/remove new field will be used rarely. Huge sized data sets are expected. Will it be suitable to maintain performance in data retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Entity attribute value pattern is one way to go.  In my opinion this becomes an anti-pattern if overused.  This has some shortcomings such as storing every value as a string.  You might find it hard to parse "true+" as a bool.  You could also do this in a weakly typed fashion or weakly typed datasets.  If you want to go this route you would actually be creating columns.  Do not give users rights to create columns, give them rights to execute a proc that creates columns.